# mysql update sequence into one table depending on another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Below are the 2 tables:

**classes**

```
            academic_year_id    student_id      standard

                    2               1               10
                    2               2               10
                    2               3               10
                    2               4               10
                    2               5               10
                    2               6               10
                    2               7               11 Science
                    2               8               11 Science
```

Here standard is not INT

**student**

```
            student_id      roll_no         name            teacher_approval

                1               0       S Sumeet G                  1
                2               0       Nair Nikhil R               1
                3               0       Nayak Ankita R              0
                4               0       Rathod Ketan P              0
                5               0       Patel Vishal D              1
                6               0       Patel Jignesh R             0
                7               0       Prajapati Bhavesh A         1
                8               0       Shah Harsh N                1
```

What i want to do:

when teacher selects standard -> 10 and press a button "Assign Roll No"

i want all student of 10th standard to be given roll no sequentially order by name and which are approved by teacher that is teacher_approval = '1'

So my student table becomes as below:

**student**

```
            student_id      roll_no         name            teacher_approval

                1               3       S Sumeet G                  1
                2               1       Nair Nikhil R               1
                3               0       Nayak Ankita R              0
                4               0       Rathod Ketan P              0
                5               2       Patel Vishal D              1
                6               0       Patel Jignesh R             0
                7               0       Prajapati Bhavesh A         1
                8               0       Shah Harsh N                1
```

I have so far tried below code:

```
$standard = $_POST['standard']

SET @incr = 0

     UPDATE
        student AS st
        JOIN
        (   SELECT * FROM
        classes AS classes
        WHERE standard = '".$standard."'
        ) AS tmp
        ON tmp.student_id = st.id
        SET
        st.roll_no = @incr:=@incr+1 
        WHERE st.teacher_approval = '1'
        ORDER BY st.name ASC
```

But it gives me an error: incorrect usage of update and order by

Anyone with a similar experience? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql,  you can't have an `ORDER BY` as part of the `UPDATE` directly when using multiple tables (see this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)). Try this instead :

```
UPDATE student AS table1
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT st.student_id, st.roll_no, st.name, st.teacher_approval
        FROM student AS st
            JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM
            classes AS cl
            WHERE cl.standard = '".$standard."'
            ) AS tmp
            ON tmp.student_id = st.student_id
            WHERE st.teacher_approval = '1'
            ORDER BY st.name ASC
        ) AS table2 
        ON table2.student_id = table1.student_id
    SET table1.roll_no = @incr:=@incr+1
```

Comment: error: The target table st of the UPDATE is not updatable

Comment: Sorry for that error. This is due to `SET st.roll_no=...`, `st` is not the table to update. It should be the `student` table.